# Google Sheets: Determining if a time falls within a two specified times

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, time, nested-if, ifs

I'm trying to find a way to determine if a time falls between two specific times - with two  different scenarios to flag. So far, I'm coming up empty (and frustrated!)

Column B has date/times such as:

```
February 9, 2022 09:55AM
February 9, 2022 01:15PM
February 9, 2022 09:39PM
```

**Flag 1:** Time is between 4AM and Noon

**Flag 2:** Time is between 8PM and 4AM -- does this need to be broken down into two separate conditions given that it spreads over midnight?

Resulting Output in Column C:

```
FLAG 1
[Blank Cell - No Flag]
FLAG 2
```

Appreciate any ideas - thanks to the community, as always.

CTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(
 (TIMEVALUE(A1:A)>=TIMEVALUE("4:00:00"))*
 (TIMEVALUE(A1:A)< TIMEVALUE("12:00:00")), "Flag 1",IF(
 (TIMEVALUE(A1:A)>=TIMEVALUE("20:00:00"))*
 (TIMEVALUE(A1:A)<=TIMEVALUE("23:59:59"))+
 (TIMEVALUE(A1:A)>=TIMEVALUE("00:00:00"))*
 (TIMEVALUE(A1:A)< TIMEVALUE("04:00:00")), "Flag 2", ))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this option, @player0!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a much simpler formula that involves a bit of math:

=arrayformula(if(A1:A="","",iferror(choose(1+mod(3+int((mod(A1:A,1)-4/24)*24/8),3),"FLAG 1","","FLAG 2"))))

We are extracting the time from the date (`mod`), offsetting the result by -4 hours (`-4/24`)and int-dividing the result by 8 hours (`*24/8, which is same as /(24/8)`) to get the index 0,1 or 2

Comment: What elegant simplicity! Thanks for this, @GoranK.

Comment: Thanks! I like it that way :)

Comment: I've noticed that this formula didn't catch times after midnight - it should have flagged it with Flag 2, but it left it blank instead. Any thoughts? It looks like it should be shifting those times backwards in your formula, but something isn't quite working right with that...

Comment: @HiDrew fixed, please check it out